# Transpose my R Dataset for association analysis

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am sort of a newbie with R and data manipulation and I am trying to transpose the UCI words dataset. The default dataset is currently structured as so.

[image]

Where the first column is the document number, the second column is the word number referencing another text file and the last column is the number of times the word occurs in the document. (For now, we can forget about the third column and I know how to drop it from the dataset.)

What I am trying to do is to transpose the dataset so that I can have each document's words in one row. So a simple example would be like this.

[image]

I tried using the `t()` function but it would transpose the entire dataset all together which is not what I want. I looked in using the dplyr package to help with the data manipulation but I am not getting any solid leads. If you guys have any sources or a particular direction you can nudge me towards accomplishing this that would helpfull.

Thank you!

Comment: What you're looking for is the `dcast` function in the `reshape2` package and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` package (which includes `dplyr`). The trick is to first add another column to differentiate entries with the same value in the first column (document number) and then just change the data to wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Your data
df <- read.csv(text = "num word
1 61
2 76
1 89
3 211
3 296", sep = " ")

df %>%
  # Group by num
  group_by(num) %>%
  # Add a rownumber to differentiate entries for the same first column value
  mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>%
  # Change data to wide format
  pivot_wider(id = num, 
              names_from = rownum,
              values_from = word)
```

Comment: Okay let me try it this way, My dataset is actually 36,000 rows long. So Ill have to edit the read.table() code from your example.

Comment: Yes. Additionally, you should change the column names so they match the ones in your data (i.e., "num" or "word").

Comment: I dont think its right, Im getting this error.

Error in UseMethod("group_by") : no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"
4.
 
group_by(., V1)
3.
 
mutate(., rownum = row_number())
2.
 
pivot_wider(., id = V1, names_from = rownum, values_from = V2)
1.
 
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(id = V1, names_from = rownum, values_from = V2)

Comment: Could you post part of your data using `dput`? It will be easier to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out how to accomplish this task. Hopefully, it helps other DS's in the future.

```
data <- read.table("docword.kos.txt", sep = " ")

data <- data %>% select(V1, V2)

trans <- data %>% 
         group_by(V1) %>%
         summarise(words = paste(V2, collapse = ","))

trans <- trans %>% select(words)
```

What I ended up doing is using the tidyr package to perform some data wrangling and group my dataset by the first column. Then I exported and re uploaded the dataset after making some slight adjustments in notepad (Replaced the " from the generated csv file)

```
write.csv(trans, "~\trend.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```